# How to create a new global symlink or command from within a node cli app?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I am not sure if I've phrased this question properly. Let me explain with an example. Consider this package.json file.

[image: package.json file]

I want my node app to create additional global commands in the user's system. My app automatically adds new command mappings to the bin field after seeking user permissions. Although its easy to internally allow the program to edit its package.json file, that does not add that new command to the user's system. That is only done once during the initial installation.

So how can I accomplish this? Is there a manual way to do this instead of depending on npm? Thanks a lot for any kind of help.

Comment: Have you tried reading [npm-link docs](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/link)

Comment: @SumanKundu Yes I have. That was the approach I tried initially by allowing the program to run 'npm link' through the node-cmd library internally. But that does not work as its not a way to create a new global command, it just a creates a new command mapping for a module that can then be later used in some other project. If you try running the command globally, it throws a "specify project-name" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is to use fs.symlink(). I dont need to edit the package.json to create symlinks or global commands. I can use fs.symlink to create symlinks to any file in my project, thus creating global commands in the user's system at will. Was a silly question because my whole thinking process was wrong to assume that I needed to edit the package.json file.